# Retornando o inverso de uma sequencia de números por recursividade em Python

Tags: python, recursão

Bem, segue meu código que visa encontrar o inverso de uma lista em python por meio da recursividade

```
def inverso(n, seq):
    if len(seq) == 0:
        return
    else:
        ultimo_valor = seq[n-1]
        print(ultimo_valor, end=' ')
        seq.pop()
        inverso((n-1), seq)
        

n = int(input())
sequencia = []
for c in range(n):
    if n >= 1 and n <= 100:
        sequencia.append(int(input()))
print(inverso(n, sequencia))
```

O problema surge no momento em que está aparecendo um None no final, coisa que não era suposta aparecer

```
#entrada
5 #tamanho da sequencia
1
3
6
4
3
```

```
#saída
3 4 6 3 1
```

É preciso que a saída esteja na mesma linha e separada por um espaço. Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Certo, obrigado. No meu caso é inverso mesmo.

Comment: A resposta é mais simples do que parece. Durante sua função inverso ele realiza prints, mas não retorna nenhum valor. Então quando você da um print de uma função que não retorna valor algum, vai aparecer o 'None'. Tente chamar a função recursiva fora do print para ver o resultado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se puder faça o mais simples.

```
print('Digite uma lista de inteiros separados por espaço:')
sequencia = [int(e) for e in input().split(" ")]

sequencia.reverse()

print(" ".join([str(e) for e in sequencia]))
```

Agora se realmente precisa usar recursão continue no simples.

```
def reverter(l):
  #Se a l estiver vazia apenas retorna []
  if len(l) == 0: return []
  #Devolve o último elemento de l mais o reverso da fatia que vai do 
  #primeiro elemento ao penúltimo elemento inclusive
  return [l[-1]] + reverter(l[:-1]) 

print('Digite uma lista de inteiros separados por espaço:')
sequencia = [int(e) for e in input().split(" ")]

sequencia = reverter(sequencia)

print(" ".join([str(e) for e in sequencia]))
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/PlasticIncomparableQuotes#main.py)</sup>